# Word Add-ins "generator-office" YO OFFICE

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I'm new with the new web Addins.
I could create an Addin with the node yo generator and was able to show the Addin in the browser.

But if I try to get it to run within windows on my office 2013, it fails. I tried it on an other pc with office 2016 and I could get it to work.

(I could only find the configuration guide for 2016. Maybe it different to 2013 https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins?product=word)
yo office
https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office

In 2013 the Addin is still disabled. Should it not also work for office 2013?

Thanks

Comment: I tried this documentation https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins, but didn't get it to work. I couldn't share the folder (missing permission) but was creating a network path.

Comment: ok, I could share this folder on my C:\\ path, but still the same

Comment: Why did you use this example? It is clearly stated: "*Applies to: Word 2016, Word for iPad, Word for Mac*". Why would you use any example which supports Word 2013? Bunch of them on github ... [InvoiceManager](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-InvoiceManager) or [AddPopulateBindings](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-AddPopulateBindings)

Comment: Hi Slava, thanks for this samples! Our customers are still on 2013. And I try to find out, how much possible is, if we want to go with this old version. If I watch this link https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability, I can see, that for 2013 only the Dialog Api 1.1 is working. Does it mean office 1.1 and not more.

Comment: Have a look at [Office Add-in host and platform availability](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability); click on "Details" of the Word for Office 2013 to see the list of supported API calls. Yes looks like API 1.1 would work with Word 2013.